# Angular async Validator debounce input

Tags: angular, forms, validation, rxjs, observable

I want to write a custom async Validator for my angular form group, which jop is to check if the url is reachable. But if i debounce the value changed from the AbstractControl the Control is always invalid somehow.
This is my code so far

```
export class UrlValidator {
static createValidator(http: HttpClient) {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
        const url = control.value;

        return http.get(url).pipe(
            throttleTime(1500),
            catchError(err => {
                console.log('err', err);
                if (err.status && err.status === 200) return of(null);
                return of({ input: 'urlError' });
            })
        );
    };
}
}
```

the debouncetime call doesn't do anything at the moment

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide more code (especially your form?)

Comment: At first look I can suggest to move http request and hist logic to separate service, dealing with this inside component/directive is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Your probably have to debounce outside of validator. Validator will get called continuously if the input source is keep emitting, putting debounce after http call doesn't do anything.

```
export class UrlValidator {
static controlValue=new Subject()
static createValidator(http: HttpClient) {
    UrlValiator.controlValue.next(control.value)
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
        return controlValue.pipe(
            debounceTime(1500),
            switchMap(()=>http(url))
            catchError(err => {
                console.log('err', err);
                if (err.status && err.status === 200) return of(null);
                return of({ input: 'urlError' });
            })
        );
    };
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem was, the Observable was stuck in the pending state. 
adding a `.first()` to the http observable did the trick